# Setting Custom JPanel at specific place in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, netbeans-7

I have designed a GV frame in GUI designer in netbeans which has 1 textArea, 2 textBoxes and 1 jButtons which are at the right side inside the frame. Now I want to add a custom JPanel in this GV frame at these components' left side. Like this: http://s25.postimg.org/3lggsdusf/Othe.png

[image]

**Main Grid Panel (directly constructed inside the class**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

    public class GV extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        boolean drawCircle = false;
        Circle circle;

        class Circle {
            Color c_color;
            int x, y, r;

            public Circle(int x, int y, int r, Color c_color) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.r = r;
                this.c_color = c_color;
            }
        }

        JPanel myGrid = new JPanel(){
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                System.out.println("paint method called");
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                if(!drawCircle){
                    g2.setPaint(Color.GRAY);
                    height = getSize().height;
                    width = getSize().width;
                    radius = (int) (Math.sqrt(height * width / 64) / 2);

                    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                        int x = i * (height / 8);
                        g2.drawLine(x, 0, x, height);
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                        int y = i * (width / 8);
                        g2.drawLine(0, y, width, y);
                    }
                }else{
                    g2.setColor(circle.c_color);
                    g2.fillOval(circle.x,circle.y,circle.r,circle.r);
                    System.err.println("Drawn @"+circle.c_color.toString()+"@"+circle.x+","+circle.y);
                    drawCircle=false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(480, 480);
            }
        };

        Game game;
        DiceType[][] board;
        int height, width, radius;
        //List<Rectangle> Cells;

        /**
         * Creates new form GV
         */
        public void drawDices(){
            board = game.board.boardGrid;
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                    if(board[i][j]!=DiceType.noDice){
                        drawDice(i+1, j+1, board[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void drawDice(int i, int j, DiceType dType){
            int x = (2*i-1)*(width/8)/2, y = (2*j-1)*(height/8)/2;;
            if(dType==DiceType.blackDice){
                circle = new Circle(x, y, radius, Color.BLACK);
            }else{
                circle = new Circle(x, y, radius, Color.WHITE);    
            }
            drawCircle=true;
            myGrid.revalidate();
            myGrid.repaint();
        }


        public void updateMovePanel(Player player){
            String moveStr="";
            for(Move move : player.Moves){
                moveStr+="["+move.xIndex+", "+move.yIndex+"]\n";
            }
            validMoveTextArea.setText(moveStr);
        }

        public GV() {

            //myGrid = new GridPanel();
            initComponents();

            //this.pack();
            game = new Game();
            drawDices();
            game.blackPlayer.findValidMoves();
            updateMovePanel(game.blackPlayer);
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            xIndexField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            yIndexField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            chooseInputasMoveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            legalMoves = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            validMoveTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            //myGrid.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            this.add(myGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            xIndexLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            yIndexLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            xIndexField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    xIndexFieldActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            chooseInputasMoveButton.setText("Choose Move");
            chooseInputasMoveButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    chooseInputasMoveButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            legalMoves.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            legalMoves.setText("Possible Moves");

            validMoveTextArea.setEditable(false);
            validMoveTextArea.setColumns(20);
            validMoveTextArea.setRows(5);
            validMoveTextArea.setEnabled(false);
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(validMoveTextArea);

            xIndexLabel.setText("X(a-h):");

            yIndexLabel.setText("Y(1-8):");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(416, 416, 416)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(xIndexLabel)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(xIndexField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(yIndexLabel)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(yIndexField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                        .addComponent(legalMoves, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(chooseInputasMoveButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(legalMoves, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 340, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(yIndexField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(xIndexField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(xIndexLabel)
                        .addComponent(yIndexLabel))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(chooseInputasMoveButton)
                    .addContainerGap())
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void chooseInputasMoveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            game.takeMove(Integer.getInteger(xIndexField.getText()), Integer.getInteger(yIndexField.getText()), game.blackPlayer);
        }                                                       

        private void xIndexFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                           

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GV.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GV.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GV.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GV.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new GV().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton chooseInputasMoveButton;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel legalMoves;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea validMoveTextArea;
        private javax.swing.JTextField xIndexField;
        private javax.swing.JLabel xIndexLabel;
        private javax.swing.JTextField yIndexField;
        private javax.swing.JLabel yIndexLabel;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

It can be seen I tried to add it the through the auto-generated initComponents() method through GUI editor but its never being added, let alone being placed at my desired area. I cant find out.

I am getting this output: http://s25.postimg.org/vmui6302n/problem_Figure.jpg

[image]

Pardon me if its a silly problem as I am a very beginner in java.

Comment: Give a link to your screen shot **image**, and we'll be able to insert it into your question. I see that you're using GroupLayout, a layout which is was built for and is useful for computer-generated code, but is very difficult to use manually. If you're creating manual layouts, you'd usually use one of the easier to use core Java layout managers or download the MigLayout.

Comment: actually I am mostly copying codes from here-and-there without knowing much to fit my panel and I know nothing about Layouts :( The rest is not copied though.

Comment: Never blindly copy code, but instead copy ***ideas*** from code. My suggestion to you then is to read the [layout tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).

Comment: Also, please give us a link to an **image** you've uploaded somewhere, not to an HTML page.

Comment: I am going to read it, but as I have tested much, I think my panels's paintComponent is never invoked when I try to add it through GV.add(myGrid).

Comment: Your image link must end in `.jpg` or `.png` or some other valid image format extension for us to be able to upload it directly into your question.

Comment: Ok. Corrected links. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but the section of the GUI you describe seems well suited to a `GridLayout`..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I think that he's trying to add the grid into a GUI created by NetBeans Matisse GUI builder, that in essence he wants to modify the layout after it's been created. I think that his best solution is to chuck the NetBeans derived code, to read the layout manager tutorials, and to hand code the GUI himself.

Comment: My problem is I cant add my grid panel at the specified place of JFrame. Though I am adding it by invoking JFrame.add(mygridPanel), its not being added. Moreover I also don't know how to do get it done, if the way is not correct I am doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I could not be able to add the panel by simply making a class extending JPanel in my project and initializing the variable. The reason was, I think, I could not lay the panel out, as I have very little knowledge about Layout-s.

So, to find a way to fulfill my necessity, I had created a class for the panel and then added it to the palette manager and designed my UI from palette. And this time, I am not drawing the dices through the panel. Here's the code:
**GridPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Shape;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author fs71gh
 */

public class GridPanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(Color.GRAY);
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            int x = i * (getHeight() / 8);
            g2.drawLine(x, 0, x, getHeight());
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            int y = i * (getWidth() / 8);
            g2.drawLine(0, y, getWidth(), y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }
}
```

Now its accomplished. Thanks to all who helped.